# Show that $\frac{W_{1}} {\left\vert W_{2} \right\vert}$ has a non-central t-distribution

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, normal-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent normal distribution i.e $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^{2})$, $Y \sim N(\mu,\sigma^{2})$. Show that $\frac{X+Y}{\left\vert X-Y \right\vert}$ has a non-central t-distrbution and what are the parmaters ?

The first things that I have done are finding the distribution of $W_{1}=X+Y$ and $W_{2}=X-Y$.

$W_{1} \sim N(2\mu, 2\sigma^{2})$ and $W_{2}\sim N(0, 2\sigma^{2})$, but I am not sure where to go from there. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$\frac {X + Y} {|X - Y|} =
\frac
 {\frac {X + Y -2 \mu} {\sigma \sqrt 2} +
  \frac {\mu \sqrt 2} \sigma}
 {\sqrt {\left( \frac {X - Y} {\sigma \sqrt 2} \right)^2} }, \\
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac {X + Y -2 \mu} {\sigma \sqrt 2} \\
\frac {X - Y} {\sigma \sqrt 2}
\end{pmatrix} \sim \mathcal N \!\left( 0,
 \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \right).$$

Therefore, $((X - Y)/(\sigma \sqrt 2))^2$ follows the chi-squared distribution with one degree of freedom and we have the definition of the noncentral t-distribution with $\nu_t = 1, \,\mu_t = \mu \sqrt 2/\sigma$. The independence requirement holds because uncorrelated components of a jointly normal distribution are independent.

Comment: Thank you so much. Would you clear up the notations for the integration in the second line? Since I am not sure you are integrating over what exactly.

Comment: It's the sum of the two double integrals of $f_{\mathcal N}((u + v)/2)) f_{\mathcal N}((u - v)/2))$. Never mind the integrals though, there is a more civilized derivation.